# How do the obstacle detection sensors work in the DJI Windows SDK?

Tags: dji-sdk

I want to get the distance of the obstacles in the back and front of the Mavic Air.
I'm using the `VissionDetectionStateChanged` and it returns values in the 4 sectors, but all of them change only with obstacles in the back. If I put my hand in the front, nothing happens.

The `VisionSensorPosition` is returning `TAIL` always and when I put my hand very close to the tail of the aircraft it changes for `NOSE`.
Shouldn't be the opposite?

Right now I just display the information, but I'd like to be able to detect obstacles in the back and front of the aircraft to try to keep it in the middle of two objects and avoid collisions.

This is my code in the event:

```
private async void FlightAssistant_VissionDetectionStateChanged(object sender, VissionDetectionState? value)
        {
            if (value.HasValue)
            {
                if (txtPosition.Dispatcher.HasThreadAccess)
                {
                    txtPosition.Text = value.Value.position.ToString();

                    for (int i = 0, count = value.Value.detectionSectors.Count; i < count; i++)
                    {
                        ObstacleDetectionSector sector = value.Value.detectionSectors[i];
                        TextBox txtWarning = this.FindControl<TextBox>("txtWarning" + i.ToString());

                        if (txtWarning != null)
                            txtWarning.Text = sector.warningLevel.ToString();

                        TextBox txtObstacleDistance = this.FindControl<TextBox>("txtObstacleDistance" + i.ToString());

                        if (txtObstacleDistance != null)
                            txtObstacleDistance.Text = sector.obstacleDistanceInMeters.ToString();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    await txtPosition.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                    {
                        txtIsSensorBeingUsed.Text = value.Value.isSensorBeingUsed.ToString();
                        txtPosition.Text = value.Value.position.ToString();

                        for (int i = 0, count = value.Value.detectionSectors.Count; i < count; i++)
                        {
                            ObstacleDetectionSector sector = value.Value.detectionSectors[i];
                            TextBox txtWarning = this.FindControl<TextBox>("txtWarning" + i.ToString());

                            if (txtWarning != null)
                                txtWarning.Text = sector.warningLevel.ToString();

                            TextBox txtObstacleDistance = this.FindControl<TextBox>("txtObstacleDistance" + i.ToString());

                            if (txtObstacleDistance != null)
                                txtObstacleDistance.Text = sector.obstacleDistanceInMeters.ToString();
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
        }
```